# Problem Saving Custom Post Type Meta Values

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta

I need a second set of eyes. I am unsure why this code is not saving properly. Basically I hit save and my field values disappear.

I have two other post-types saving fine using this structure. I feel I've just been looking at a screen too long and am missing something. :) Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Nadine

```
<?php 
// adding a custom post type for books 
add_action('init', 'books_register');

function books_register() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Books', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Book', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'Book'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Book'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Book'),
        'new_item' => __('New Book'),
        'view_item' => __('View Book'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Books'),
        'not_found' =>  __('No Books found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Books found in Trash'),
        //'has_archive' => true,
        'parent_item_colon' => ''


    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array('title','editor','author','excerpt','thumbnail'),
        'taxonomies' => array('book_publisher','post_tag'),

      ); 

    register_post_type( 'tf_books' , $args );

    // make some taxonomies

    register_taxonomy('book_publishers','tf_books',
        array(
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'label' => 'Book Publisher',
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => true
        )
    );  

    add_action("admin_init", "tf_book_deets_create");

        function tf_book_deets_create(){
            // this is for sorting the post
            add_meta_box('tf_book_details', 'Book Details', 'tf_book_details', 'tf_books');
        }

        // values and output (or where it ALWAYS FUCKS UP)

        function tf_book_details () {
            global $post;

            $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);

            $article_date = $custom["tf_book_author"][0];
            $article_date = $custom["tf_book_afirst"][0];
            $article_date = $custom["tf_book_isbn"][0];
            $article_date = $custom["tf_book_dts"][0];
            $article_date = $custom["tf_book_price"][0];



            ?>

            <div class="admin_meta"> 
                <ul>
                    <li><label>Author Last Name:</label><input name="tf_book_author" value="<?php echo $tf_book_author; ?>" /></li>
                    <li><label>Author First Name:</label><input name="tf_book_afirst" value="<?php echo $tf_book_afirst; ?>" /></li>
                    <li><label>Book ISBN:</label><input name="tf_book_isbn" value="<?php echo $tf_book_isbn; ?>" /></li>
                    <li><label>Book Details:</label><input name="tf_book_dts" value="<?php echo $tf_book_dts; ?>" /></li>
                    <li><label>Book Price:</label><input name="tf_book_price" value="<?php echo $tf_book_price; ?>" /></li> 
                </ul>
            </div> 

        <?php
        } // end of book details


        // save this shit

        add_action ('save_post', 'save_book_details');  

        function save_tf_book_details(){ 
        global $post;

        update_post_meta($post->ID, "tf_book_author", $_POST["tf_book_author"]);    
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "tf_book_afirst", $_POST["tf_book_afirst"]);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "tf_book_isbn", $_POST["tf_book_isbn"]);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "tf_book_dts", $_POST["tf_book_dts"]);  
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "tf_book_price", $_POST["tf_book_price"]);

        }


} // end of book_deets_create() ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$article_date = $custom["tf_book_author"][0];
$article_date = $custom["tf_book_afirst"][0];
$article_date = $custom["tf_book_isbn"][0];
$article_date = $custom["tf_book_dts"][0];
$article_date = $custom["tf_book_price"][0];
```

This is your issue. You need to set these to `$tf_book_author` and such, especially if you're going to echo them. I stopped there, so there may be more errors in the code, but that's the first one to knock out.

Comment: Welp, that's a sign I've been looking at too many screens to not notice something that obvious. Thanks.

Changed them, but its still not updating.

Comment: Found it! Didn't set up the last function right. Sorry to bother folks. proof that I should sleep. Thanks. :)